draw small spheres on cube vertices in 3D using tikz
I am trying to draw a cube with spheres on 4 vertices in perspective (I'll have then to insert a gray transparent plane but that seems doable). I am dealing with the first sphere... for which I tried to use a \fill[ball] command, but this flatten the circle as it is not a real 3D ball but rather a 2D circle... would anyone have suggestions on how to plot spheres on 4 corners ? (I try to produce a tetrahedral symmetry for more details so I'll also have a sphere in the center of the cube).
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view,scale=2]
    \draw (0,0,0)--(1,0,0);
    \draw (0,1,0)--(0,0,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1,0,0)--(1,1,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1,1,0)--(0,1,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1,1,0)--(1,1,1);
    \draw (0,0,1)--(1,0,1)--(1,1,1)--(0,1,1)--cycle;
    \draw (0,0,0)--(0,0,1);
    \draw (1,0,0)--(1,0,1);
    \draw (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
    \fill[ball color=blue!20,opacity=1.7] (0,0,1) circle (0.05) node[above] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}  

and what it produces:

Have a good day !
Marc

If you want the lines to intersect the "spheres" properly, you will need a software which is more 3D-capable than tikz. Asymptote offers better suitability for 3D, for instance.

Thanks a lot for your suggestion, Jasper. I don't know Asymptote at the moment but I'll definitely take a look: it seems very promising !

if the goal is only to draw an element that looks like a sphere, we can use the {shadings} (https://tikz.dev/library-shadings)  library on a ball type node.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view,scale=2]
    \draw (0,0,1)coordinate(a)--(1,0,1)coordinate(b)--(1,1,1)coordinate(c)--(0,1,1)coordinate(d)--cycle;
    \draw (0,1,0)coordinate(h)--(0,0,0)coordinate(e)--(1,0,0)coordinate(f);
    \draw[dashed] (1,0,0)--(1,1,0)coordinate(g)--(1,1,1);;
    \draw[dashed] (1,1,0)--(0,1,0);
    \draw (0,0,0)--(0,0,1);
    \draw (1,0,0)--(1,0,1);
    \draw (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
\shade[ball color=red] (a) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=yellow] (b) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=blue] (c) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=pink] (d) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=brown] (e) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=green] (f) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=purple] (g) circle (1mm);
\shade[ball color=gray] (h) circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If you just want to use the ball shading, you don't even need the shadings library.

Note that the circle[radius=1mm] is favoured over circle (1mm) syntax-wise.

Thanks a lot @rpapa ! How is that different from what I did ? I am very beginner in tikz - among other things...
